How to install Gleam on Ubuntu
Well, I think the title is enough straight forward - I'd like to install Gleam (the programming language) on Ubuntu.
I looked in the official documentation, but it seems I couldn't find anything useful.
Maybe I have to install something like brew and then install gleam, because I tried with apt and failed.
Hope someone can help.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour]. If the "official documents" don't mention the Installation Requirements, and those requirements don't mention Linux,  probably not. Depending which "Gleam" you mean, an apt-cache search gleam will show you what's avaliable.

Thank you, I looked into the documentation and there were some linux systems, but no one with apt. I also tried that command of yours, but I got an ambigous answer, something like this: elpa-format-all - Auto-format C, C++, JS, Python, Ruby and 50 other languages.

Gleam is installed on Linux using Homebrew.
First install Homebrew (more details here) with the command
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Then, if you want, you can add Homebrew to your PATH variable (docs here) with the following command
test -d ~/.linuxbrew && eval "$(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
test -d /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
echo "eval \"\$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)\"" >> ~/.bashrc

Gleam can be installed on Linux using Homebrew (instructions here)
brew update
brew install gleam

If you get this error: Error: no implicit conversion of false into String while trying to install gleam, then you can solve it with this:
export HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1
brew tap homebrew/core
brew update
brew reinstall gleam


This may be an answer but since it does not contain the info but only links it is not. For it to be an answer the info needs to be something that can be read here.

Hi, thank you for your answer. I run those commands and it worked, even though I had to set brew in the PATH variable.

@Osisho I edited the answer and added the command to set Homebrew in the PATH variable.

I also added (to the answer) a possible solution to an error that occurred to me while installing gleam. Hope my edit gets accepted.
